# TCL/TK: the entry show the text in right side

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is that possible to display the string in an entry adjust to the right instead of left?
Fox example, there is a string "/temp/test/2017/0910/test.txt", and the entry can't display the total string. If I want to show the right part of the string without change the entry width, how to do? Thanks!

```
global path
set path "/temp/test/2017/0910/test.txt"
entry .e -textvariable path
grid .e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.e xview moveto 1.0` to see the rightmost part of the string in your entry field.

I'd also add `.e icursor end` to put the insertion cursor to the very end of the field too. Otherwise it won't be visible when you switch focus to the entry (via the `TAB` key) which is inconvenient.